# How to install HttpClient library from Apache?

Tags: java, installation, httpclient

`import org.apache.http.client.*;`

I want to import this java package it says that it doesn't exist, so where should I download this package from, and where to install it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can download the jar file from the [Maven Repository](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/maven2/commons-httpclient/commons-httpclient/).

You just need to place the jar on the classpath, no need to install anything.

Comment: Can I ask you which specific file should I download?

Comment: I would recommend the jar for version [3.1](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/maven2/commons-httpclient/commons-httpclient/3.1/commons-httpclient-3.1.jar) since it's the latest release.

Comment: I see the binary download comes with several JAR files (about 10) Do I need to install only httpclient or all of the JARs?

Answer (score 1):

ypu can download it from here . 
http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/
You will need to add it to the build path (if you are using eclipse).